# React testing library - test descendant elements

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

For example, I have a component like this:

```
export const MyDiv = ({ faClassName, children }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {faClassName && <i className={faClassName} />}
      <div>{children}</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

And test:

```
it('Should render the component with all element', () => {
  render(<MyDiv faClassName="fa fa-pencil">Hello</MyDiv>)

  // more code here
}
```

I don't know how to test that there's an `i` tag in the container and the text `Hello` is wrapped by a `div` tag (not another tag).

Comment: You can add a role or testId to icon element and if faClassName is not empty string, you expect that testId to be in the document, there are several aproaches

Comment: Yeah but I can't modify the Component, I just write the test.
I'm new to testing, and to a component like this, we can't use `getByRole` or `getByText` right?

Comment: Ok, so as you know that the i element provides a span, you can expect the span to be in the document and you dont need to modify component, and if className is empty string, that span you expect it not to be in the document. Also expect that the text you provide in the children is in the document or have text content hello

Comment: In that case you cant use getByRole because you didnt provide it in the i element, you cant use getByText because the i element has no text, maybe you can use querySelector and pass the className of the icon, something like this: screen.querySelector('the name of the class you provide to icon'), and then expect this to be in the document

Comment: Your welcome, i hope it works!!